# FTDI chip based custom board. Driver not working

Tags: ftdi

I designed a board containing a USB to UART bridge in order to program a ATmega microcontroller. I copied the schematic of this breakout board from Sparkfun

https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9716

This is my schematic:

[image]

I install FTDI drivers from this link:

http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/VCP.htm

in "windows - setup executable". It doesn't work. My computer doesn't recognize it. I have windows 8.1 and I think it could be related. I disabled device driver signatures.

I don't know what to do now. I don't think it's related with my schematic, but I can't solve this problem.

Any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm assuming you got the chip from a reputable dealer?

Comment: Mouser I believe. I didn't assemble the board, but I gave to the manufacturer a bill of materials with Mouser part numbers as reference.

Comment: Does it see any new device connected (even not recognized one)? If negative I would assume hardware failure (check voltages, connections etc)

Comment: What *exactly* does your computer do when it "doesnt recognise it"?

Comment: With the reset pin floating, I would be surprised if anything happened.

Comment: @MattYoung It is actually working this way... verified several times :)

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes it recognices a new device. It says "unknown USB device" in devices manager. If I unplug it, it disappears.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I am automatically suspicious of any active low reset that is not pulled up.

Comment: Any LED's are blinking upon the plugin?

Comment: @MattYoung Yeah, but in this case the datasheet explicitly states: Active low reset pin. This can be used by an external device to reset the
FT232R. If not required can be left unconnected, or pulled up to VCC.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yeah, TX and RX leds blink 5 times when I plug it.

Comment: @Grant. My computer shows a message "usb device not recognized" when I plug it in.

Comment: Sounds like the USB data lines are not connected, or connected in a wrong way, because it looks like the power is OK.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I carefully checked USB lines (0402 components are small) and I found that one of those 27 ohm resistors is soldered badly. Great manufacturer work. I'm going to solder it properly and I'll try again.

Comment: @EugeneSh. You were right. Data lines were not conected (one resistor was soldered badly). I fixed it and now it works perfect. Thank you.

Comment: You might want to go back and re-download that driver.  Not that it will solve your immediate problem, but they recently released one that will cleverly detect and "brick" counterfeit FTDI chips, including those that are buried in other products.  Then they discovered that people don't like having their stuff bricked and so they fixed it.  I'd hate for you to go through all the trouble of making it work, see it finally connect...and go dead again.

Answer (score 1):

If by "my computer doesnt recognize it" you mean you can't run the exe to install the drivers, you probably have a corrupt download.  Download the file again and see if it works.

If you mean the installer worked just fine, but the drivers aren't working properly, then you either hooked it up wrong, have a defective FTDI chip, or have a counterfit chip.

Comment: Hi Grant. I can install the drivers. It says installation was finished correctly. When I plug it in my computer shows a message "USB device not recognized"

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved. As Eugene Sh suggested, it was a problem with USB lines. I didn't assemble the board so I supossed it was properly soldered, but it wasn't. I fixed one resistor (R4 in my schematic) and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Were the D+/D- differential pair laid out on the PCB appropriately?  Have you attempted to look at the USB enumeration with a protocol analyzer?  I believe for a device to be recognized, all that needs to happen is the 1.5K pull-up is present, so I would lean towards incorrect signaling environment as the culprit.

Also, your schematics don't show an oscillator, but there are pins for an oscillator.  While I'm unfamiliar with this exact part, most of the USB device ICs I have used have required a 12/24/48MHz crystal.